# Gerar mês subsequente in R

Tags: r, datetime, data

Como faço para colocar o mês subsequent?

```
df1
dt          nome idade
01/03/2018  ll    15
07/03/2019  dd    33
31/12/2019  ff    44
```

Após regras

```
df1
dt          nome idade
01/03/2018  ll    15
01/04/2019  dd    33
01/01/2020  ff    44
```

A regra é a seguinte, caso o dia seja diferente de "01" o mesmo terá que ter o dia como "01" do mês subsequente, como mostra o df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando os pacotes lubridate e dplyr:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

#Criando o data.frame cedido. A função dmy converte para o formato data
df1 <- data.frame(dt = c(dmy("01/03/2018"), dmy("07/03/2019"), dmy("31/12/2019")),
                  nome = c("11", "ff", "dd"),
                  idade = c(15,33,44))

#O paste cria a data "01/mês/ano" da linha, %m+% adiciona o mês
#sem estourar a data limite do mês anterior, e months(1) a quantidade de mêses a serem somadas
df1 %>%
  mutate(dt2 = dmy(paste("01", month(dt), year(dt)))  %m+% months(1))          
dt nome idade        dt2
1 2018-03-01   11    15 2018-04-01
2 2019-03-07   ff    33 2019-04-01
3 2019-12-31   dd    44 2020-01-01
```